# How to determine physical location of hard drives?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have a system with 2 power supplies and 12 hard drives - 8 of which are on my Highpoint RocketRAID 2320 controller (4 are in RAID0 for backup) and the other 4 are split across 2 controllers on my mainboard. I'm trying to do some restructuring to build a better RAID *and* reduce the number of drives by replacing the < 1TB drives with 2-3TB drives. The problem is I'm having a tough time determining where each drive is *physically* located. Currently the best method I have is to unplug one drive, boot up and wait 7 minutes until my system is "usable". This process naturally takes forever and is rather frustrating.

Does anyone have any tips/tricks to speed this process up?

btw this is a Windows 7 64-bit system.

Comment: This is the side effect of RAID.  RAID does such a good job of making all the drives look like one drive that the OS has **no idea**.  Another word for it is abstraction.

Comment: Good point. But only 4 drives are in RAID mode. The other 4 are used as single disks. Even knowing what these 4 are would help considerably.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, when you're using hardware RAID controllers, I don't believe you can see the serial numbers of the hard drives in the disk management tool because hardware RAID makes each set of drives appear as a single drive to Windows.  You should be able to see the serial number by going through the properties of each drive for any non-RAID drives this way.  But, you should be able to determine from this which drive letters are located on which RAID controllers.

If you then take your compiled list of arrays and drive letters, you can go into each RAID's setup utility and see if they will list the serial number of each drive associated in each array.  If you can get that far, you can then look at the serial number on the sticker on each physical drive and compare that to your list to see which physical drives are eventually associated with each drive letter.

Not as simple as I think you're hoping for, but could be a little faster than your trial and error method.  Unfortunately, using hardware RAID controllers, it somewhat prevents the easy solution of just looking it up in Windows Disk Management tool.